# Wordpress App Services with Path mapping very slow

Tags: wordpress, azure, performance, containers, volumes

I'm currently migrating a wordpress installation to azure app services with containers. First I did a normal installation with everything inside the container for testing purpose. The performance was good and and things worked without problems.

Then I wanted to add the wp-content folder to a persistent folder, for this I created a file share and added it under Path mappings. This worked without problems and after the restart Wordpress could access the files.

But now every page load takes about 1-2 minutes and the page as whole is unusable in this stage. I double checked the the file share settings and everything else. Share is optimized for transactions and as soon as I remove the volume, the container is fast as light again.

Does anyone have the same problem? Any ideas how to fix this? This is a deal break for me tbh.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not answering your question directly but an alternative is to use App Service Persistent Storage that store data in /home folder of the VM where your app is running.  It should be a lot faster then using a File Share in a storage account.  The **${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}** maps to the **/home** folder.

You need to enable by setting **WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE** to true in the application settings or by using the CLI:

```
az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group <group-name> --name <app-name> --settings WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I will give this a try but not the solution I'm targeting. :)